# Mongo console aggregate with $match and $group and list of records

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Need a Mongo console for aggregation with $match and $group and list of records.

I'm new to mongo console db collection.

The following is incorrect. I am seeking approaches to get list aggregate results based on collection $match. I need to get a list of the results from this aggregation by year. I have an illegal key in $sort.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{EVENT_TYPE:"something"}},{"$group":{_id:"EVENT_TYPE"}},{$sort:{_id:"YEAR"
}}])
```

Comment: Please show your sample data and the result you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I was working all day and stopped my VM instance, start again on Monday and post some sample data.

Comment: Np. It's just hard to visualize it without having something solid to work against.

Comment: The aggregation syntax requires prefixing a field with a `$`, ( `{ "$group": { _id: "$EVENT_TYPE" } }` ) for the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage.